# flash player for merging (and playing) multiple movies

Tags: flash

I am looking for a flash player that can play multiple movies on top of each other. Starting with two movies of similar length, the player will stream both movies and overlay movie1 on top of movie2. Of course, one of these must have a transparent background.  I want the player to receive several links and retrieve those movies and play them together.

If there is no player that does this, does flash make it possible to write one?  It seems most people use flex to write flash players and while I have not looked into it yet, I was wondering if anyone could argue why or why not it would be possible?

I have no experience in flash players, so I'm sorry if there is any mis-understanding.

P.S. I want to use this flash player in facebook so facebook supported flash players are a plus.

Answer (score 0):

You can use class Video for streaming movies and class Loader for externally loaded timelines. Overlay them in necessary order and synchronize playback by the lower playing time of loaded content.

Comment: After looking for some open source flash players, I decided on flowplayer since it seems to most supported.  However, I am not sure if I need to change the code to the player itself or if I can write a plugin that can achieve what I want.  It seems you are familiar with ActionScript so do you have any suggestions?